# Moving to TypeScript: Need to define interface for each database table for destructuring?

Tags: typescript, pg-promise

I just started porting my project from JavaScript to TypeScript. Things feel reasonably straightforward, but I'm wondering what best practice is for typing the responses to PostgreSQL queries (using pg-promise). I have about 20 tables in the database.

I have found three solutions for assigning type when destructuring, but all seem really clunky.

1. Use the destructuring syntax in for each db call. A LOT of extra typing and makes code hard to read.

```
const { name, age }: { name: string; age: number } = await db.query(...)
```

2. Define a local interface just before each call. Works even when joining tables. Cleaner than #1 but still a lot of busywork.

```
interface qData { name: string; age: number };
const data: qData = await db.query(...);
```

3. Create an interface file for each table, and make sure to keep it in synch with table definitions at all times. Seems risky, and I'm not sure how to handle situations when I'm doing a query from several joined tables?

```
export interface table1Types { name: string; age: number };
export interface table2Types { etc etc};
...
export interface table20Types {bla bla};
```

#3 seems like the least bad, but are there better ways? And if I go with #3, how do I handle joined tables?

Comment: There are libraries out there, like [schemats](https://github.com/SweetIQ/schemats) to help with generating classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fourth way that isn't as tedious and hard to keep in synch with the database definition. I created two types:

```
type qRow = { [key: string]: any};
type qRows = Array<qRow>;
```

This allows me to do the below, which catches my most common error: forgetting that the return is an array even if I'm sure there is only one  row being returned.

```
const res: qRows = await db.query("....");
```

I can also do this, which feels neat:

```
res.forEach( (r: qRow) => { some cool stuff});
```

Comment: The whole purpose of moving to TypeScript is for strict type control. Your answer is missing that completely, and doesn't really follow your own question.